# How is HttpContext.Current scoped to the Request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to create an `ApiContext.Current` similar to `HttpContext.Current` but I don't want to use `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

If `ApiContext.Current` is a static property.

```
public class ApiContextSnapshot {
    public Guid AppId { get; set; }
}

public static class ApiContext {
    public static ApiContextSnapshot Current { get; set; }
}
```

The issue with this is that concurrent requests will overwrite/use the same static class. How does `HttpContext.Current` do this so that concurrent requests have their own *static class*?

**Per mjwillis**

So they are using `CallContext.HostContext`. So `HttpContext.Current` returns `CallContext.HostContext`?

If I wanted to do something similiar, should I use `CallContext.SetData` and `CallContext.HostData`?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you don't want to use `HttpContext.Current.Items` ? Are you using an IoC container (if so, some of those can help for these kinds of problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` doesn't work like that. You have defined a standard auto-implemented property, so there is only one 'value'.

But `HttpContext.Current` appears to ultimately call down into `CallContext.HostContext` which is defined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs). My guess is that ASP.NET / IIS / something sets that property at the start of the web request.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html is also likely worth a read as an option to consider. Although, to be honest, i think you should use `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

Comment: I've updated my original question per your answer here.